# CodeIgniter Sessions userdata issues

Tags: codeigniter, session

Having real big problems with CodeIgniter sessions. I can't get any userdata, really unusual thing, who can help me? I don't know how to realize it, I'm not getting the session.

Here is code:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('admin_model');
    }

    public function do_login($username,$password)
    { 
        $right_login = $this->admin_model->get_username($username);
        $right_password = $this->admin_model->get_password($password);

        if( ! empty($right_login) &&  ! empty($right_password))
        {
            $session = array();
            $session['admin_logined'] = 'yes';
            $session['user_ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            $this->session->set_userdata($session);

            redirect('admin/main');
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('admin');
        }   
    }

    public function do_logout()
    {  
        $session = array();
        $session['admin_logined'] = '';
        $session['user_ip'] = '';
        $this->session->unset_userdata($session);
        redirect('admin');
    }   

    public function check_admin()
    {    
        if(($this->session->userdata('admin_logined') === "yes"))
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('admin');
        }
     }

 }
```

Comment: tried everything, but no result

Comment: Have you loaded the session library? `$this->load->library('session');`

Comment: it's on autload, of course

Comment: Are there any error messages? Have you set the encryption key in your config?

Answer (score 0):

To get session working in codeigniter you have to loaded session library to your controller constructor .

`$this->load->library('session');` for more detail [Codeigniter session](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html).

Comment: i have seen manual many times, it's loaded autmoatically via autoload function

Comment: more you can do 1: Give your `$config['base_url']` setting a value
2:Remove any underscores from your `sess_cookie_name` cookie_prefix
Make sure cookie_domain is properly set. 3:This may mean removing it altogether